# Java: Time Format Precison

Tags: java, time, decimal, time-format

I have a number that is time in milliseconds. 
How do I display it in

```
Hour:mm:ss:+ 2 or 3 decimals
```

Comment: Look at SimpleDateFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [java convert milliseconds to time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean with?

```
long timeInMillis = 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String text = sdf.format(new Date(timeInMillis));
```

or you can build the string yourself

```
long timeInMillis = 3032;
String text = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d.%03d", 
        timeInMillis / 3600000,
        timeInMillis / 60000 % 60,
        timeInMillis / 1000 % 60,
        timeInMillis % 1000);
System.out.println(text);
```

prints

```
0:00:03.032
```

Comment: "Dates" have milli-second resolution and are recorded in milli-seconds.

Comment: if I input 3032, the output is 01:00:03:032
...where did the 1 came from??

Comment: Ok so after research it depends where I live. I dont want my game to output 1 more hour because i live in Europe.

Comment: Sorry, the timezone can cause problems.  You don't have to use simple date format.

Comment: You can calculate it yourself.