# Convertings mills to hh mm ss

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mills {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter milliseconds");
    long mills= sc.nextLong();

    System.out.println(convertMillis(mills));

    }

    public static String convertMillis(long millis){

        long s = (millis / 1000) % 60;
        long m = (millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long h = (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%d",s,m,h);
        return time;
    }
}
```

I am stuck, I don't know what to do after.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier 'd'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at Mills.convertMillis(Mills.java:19)
    at Mills.main(Mills.java:10)
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java

Comment: @APaul Looks like a duplicate to me...

Comment: yes. Thats why I mentioned to check this. He has done a structure error that he can figure out from this post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java convert milliseconds to time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format)

Answer (score 3):

You have 4 `%d` in the `String.format()` but only 3 values. Remove the last `%d` or add another value.

```
String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", s, m, h); // remove a %d
```

or

```
String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%d", s, m, h, anotherVal); // add another value
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to do this all together!! Just use SimpleDateFormat class Like this:

```
    long millis = 0;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(millis);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

Just replace the 0 with your millis.

Comment: Just remember that Calendar's reference date is the "Epoch" which is January 1st 1970 00:00:00. The date will be calculated relative to that, but if you are in the range of less than 24 hours, this should work fine...

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 "%d"s in the format string but provide only 3 arguments... Try removing the last %d

```
public static String convertMillis(long millis){

    long s = (millis / 1000) % 60;
    long m = (millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    long h = (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
    String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",s,m,h);
    return time;
}
```