# Is there a letter for the milliseconds since 1970 in SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, timestamp

Is there a letter for the milliseconds since 1970 in [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)? I know about the `getTime()` method but I want to define a date and time pattern containing the milliseconds.

Comment: Can you read the page you linked? If there is, it will be listed there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format?rq=1

Comment: According to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) it doesn't look like there is one

Comment: I can read and I didn't find it. So with the current question I wanted to make sure that there really isn't such a letter. Probably there is a reason for it. Maybe someone can tell me.

Answer (score 8):

`SimpleDateFormat` does not have a symbol (letter) for inserting the milliseconds since the beginning of the epoch starting at 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Reason: Frankly just inserting the milliseconds since the beginning of the epoch is just inserting the `long` value returned by `Date.getTime()`, the value how an instant in time (`Date`) is represeneted, which is not very useful when your goal is to create a human-readable, formatted date/time string. So I don't see having a symbol for this being justified. You can append this number easily or have its value included as you would with any other simple number.

However, there is an alternative: `String.format()`

`String.format()` uses a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) which also supports Date/Time conversions which is very similar to the pattern of `SimpleDateFormat`.

For example there is a symbol `'H'` for the Hour of the day (24-hour clock), `'m'` for Month (two digits) etc., so in most cases `String.format()` can be used instead of `SimpleDateFormat`.

What you're interested in is also has a symbol: `'Q'`: Milliseconds since the beginning of the epoch starting at 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

What's even better, `String.format()` is flexible enough to accept both `long` values and `Date`s as the input parameter for Date/Time conversions.

Usage:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%tQ", System.currentTimeMillis()));
System.out.println(String.format("%tQ", new Date()));

// Or simply:
System.out.printf("%tQ\n", System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.printf("%tQ\n", new Date());

// Full date+time+ millis since epoc:
Date d = new Date();
System.out.printf("%tF %tT (%tQ)", d, d, d);
// Or passing the date only once:
System.out.printf("%1$tF %1$tT (%1$tQ)", d);

// Output: "2014-09-05 11:15:58 (1409908558117)"
```