# Timestamp to this particular format

Tags: java, timestamp, jodatime, simpledateformat, epoch

I've done lots of epoch time to string date conversions

but I never remember if I use some date time object or SimpleDateFormat or JodaTime or Calendar method, and they all have their own legends for formatting. On top of that, I'm not sure if I need to divide my epoch object by 1000 or something to make the timestamp conversion work correctly, it is very... time... consuming

so how would I convert an epoch timestamp to this format "March 16, 8:01 EDT" , where 8:01 is 24 hour time, and EDT is a timezone abbreviation

Comment: possible duplicate of [java convert milliseconds to time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using JodaTime for this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd, HH:mm z");
dtf = dtf.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(dtf.print(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```