# Time in millis to String timestap incorrect by 1 hour

Tags: java, android, timestamp, sms

I am getting getTimestampMillis() from a SmsMessage sms and trying to convert that to MM/dd/yy hh:mm a.

I am using the code below, which works except it returns an hour ahead.  Example it is 6-28-15 9:22 pm, the code returns 6-28-15 10:22 pm.  I have read this is a java bug because London didnt observe GMT in 1970, or something similar.  Is there a fix, or workaround that doesn't require me to subtract an hour in the summer and then change the code back after DST?

```
long time = currentMessage.getTimestampMillis();
                Log.i(TAG, "time stamp in millis= "+time);
                Time date = new Time(time);
                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy hh:mm a");
                String timestamp = format.format(date);
                Log.i(TAG, "Human readable timestamp= "+timestamp);
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Time`, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the last two in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert timestamp in milliseconds to string formatted time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/convert-timestamp-in-milliseconds-to-string-formatted-time-in-java) Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781577/convert-from-millisecond-to-string-of-date)?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch )
```

[GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) represents [mean solar time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_time#Mean_solar_time), and is practically synonymous with [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Do not confuse this with the time zone [`Europe/London`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_Kingdom) which has observed [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

## *java.time*

Never use `java.sql.Time`, `DateFormat`, or any of the legacy date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

The modern solution uses *java.time* classes.

I assume your count of milliseconds was since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = currentMessage.getTimestampMillis();
```

Convert to a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

An `Instant` is always in UTC, by definition. So you will not have any surprises from Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

You did not specify your example value of epoch milliseconds. But we can work backwards to deduce it.

```
// Example it is 6-28-15 9:22 
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.JUNE , 28 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 9 , 22 ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
long epochMilli = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

> 1435483320000

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/kGe0cn).

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score -1):

UTC and GMT are two different things.  UTC does not experience DST, whereas GMT does.  Two steps:
1.  Find out what time standard your host is actually using (java will be using this).
2.  Probably just ignore that completely, and explicitly declare which timezone you want to use.

And if you find that playing with timezones is tedious, annoying, and confusing, consider using library joda-time.  It's much more versatile and pleasant to use than built-in java stuff.

Comment: **Incorrect.** GMT does not adjust for Daylight Saving Time (DST). GMT represents solar time. For practical everyday purposes, GMT is synonymous with UTC. I suspect you had `Europe/London` time zone in mind which does indeed observe DST. See [*Time in the United Kingdom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_Kingdom) in Wikipedia.