# Convert from Millisecond to String of Date

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, datetime-conversion

I try to convert from Milliseconds to string of date. However, the result is not correct as my expected.

The input is milliseconds (Ex: `1508206600485`)

My time zone is `UTC +10:00`

```
------Expected-------------------------------------------- Actual------

01:32 (PM) 17/10/2017--------------------------------02:32 (PM) 17/10/2017
```

Here is the method of that

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm dd/MM/yyyy");
    String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(milliSeconds));
    return dateString;
}
```

Comment: What is the input and what time zone is the code running in?

Comment: the input is milliseconds

Comment: Yes, but what's the actual number?  And what's your time zone?  Or more importantly, what time zone is the Locale on your computer?

Comment: I did not know there is a timezone, so how I can know what my time zone is

Comment: Note that nowadays one should not use `Date` anymore, its **legacy**. Use the new Time API instead, it is located inside the package `java.time`

Comment: Sorry, I just edited

Comment: really I get `11:16 17/10/2017`

Comment: Is this a problem of DayLight Saving?

Comment: OK, so 1508206600485 milliseconds is 17456 days, 2 hours, 16 minutes and 40(ish) seconds.  So if you were in UTC, it would be 2:16am.  Since you're in UTC+10:00 (somewhere in Australia?) it should be 12:16pm.  Why are you expecting 1:32pm for your output?

Comment: I have not set time zone for my `SimpleDateFormat`. The problem sovled when I add `formater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));`

Comment: so you are getting the milliseconds from some other TZ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good [you found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46781748/7605325), I just like to add an approach with **Java 8** [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and it's strongly recommended to switch to the new API if possible.

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

To convert the millis value to a specific timezone, you can use the `Instant` class, then use a `ZoneId` to convert to a timezone, creating a `ZonedDateTime`.
Then you use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format it:

```
// convert millis value to a timezone
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1508206600485L);
ZonedDateTime z = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney"));
// format it
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(fmt.format(z)); // 01:16 17/10/2017
```

The output is:

> 01:16 17/10/2017

Note that I used `hh` for the hours. [According to javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), this lettern represents the **clock-hour-of-am-pm** field (values from 1 to 12), so without the AM/PM indicator, it can be ambiguous. Maybe you want to add AM/PM field (adding the letter `a` to the format pattern), or change the hours to `HH` (**hour-of-day**, with values from 0 to 23).

Also note that the actual value of the `ZonedDateTime` is `2017-10-17T13:16:40.485+11:00` (**01:16 PM**), because in October 17<sup>th</sup> 2017, [Sydney is in Daylight Saving Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/australia/sydney?year=2017), so the actual offset is `+11:00`.

Comment: This is the correct way to solve this.  I'm still wondering (1) why OP's expected output was 1:32pm, (2) why OP's time zone wasn't correct to start with.  Your solution doesn't address those issues; but I've upvoted it here because it's the best thing to show to anyone who stumbles across this question in the future.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Item 1, I guess it's probably a typo or OP actually tested with another input value. Item 2, I based on OP's own answer saying that Sydney timezone solved the problem - maybe DST wasn't being considered, as Sydney actually uses +10:00 offset when not in DST. Or maybe their JVM default timezone is set to a different one, who knows...

Comment: Yeah, probably.  I was thinking of voting to close the question as "can't reproduce", which of course would also cover the typo case.  However, your answer here now makes it worth keeping the question.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on @phlaxyr, I have solved my problem. You can get your time zone in this link below

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm dd/MM/yyyy");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
    String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(milliSeconds));
    return dateString;
}
```