# Convert milliseconds to date string back and forth using java 7

Tags: date, java-7

I have the following code which uses all recommendations discussed in similar questions.

```
public class DateUtils {
static String secondsToDate(String seconds) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(seconds) * 1000);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return String.format("%d-%d-%d", year, month, day);
}

static String dateToSeconds(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try {
        Date parsed = format.parse(date);
        long timeInMillis = parsed.getTime();
        return Long.toString(timeInMillis / 1000);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String timestamp = "1409515200";
    String date = secondsToDate(timestamp);
    String timestamp2 = dateToSeconds(date);
    System.out.printf("%s  %s", timestamp, timestamp2);
}
}
```

The result of the code:

```
1409515200  1406836800
```

As you can see the conversion back and forth doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java convert milliseconds to time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is the rounding. In the first method, you are converting your timestamp (which is the number of **milliseconds** from 1970) into a date. You are now getting only the date, discarding hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds and converting it back. This means that you will always have a difference of the amount you are discarding (between 0 at 00:00:00:000 and 86400000 at 23:59:59:999). To fix it, simply change your date format to include the hours with milliseconds precision.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Aurasphere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37121939/642706) is correct and should be accepted.

Some further tips…

Use date-time classes for date-time values, rather than strings. Perform your business logic using date-time objects, and pass around such objects amongst your code rather than strings.

Avoid tracking date-times as a count-from-epoch. When you do need to serialize to text, use the unambiguous and easy-to-read formats defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard such as `2016-05-09T16:47:54Z`.

You are using old troublesome legacy classes that have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of that functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted for Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Using java.time classes will make your work easier and your code easier to comprehend, less likely to encounter the confusion seen in the Question.

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC, with a resolution of nanoseconds. That class offers a convenient factory method [`ofEpochSecond`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-), so no need to multiply by a thousand for milliseconds.

```
String input = "1409515200";
long seconds = Long.parseLong( input );
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( seconds );
```

To get the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) for some locality, assign a time zone to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

To generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format, call [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString--). Note that this method extends that format to append the name of the time zone in square brackets. For example, `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`.

```
String output = zdt.toString();
```

To get the date-only as in the Question, extract a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

From there you can determine the first moment of the day. The first moment is not always the time-of-day `00:00:00.0`, so let java.time determine that.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfDay = localDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

To get the two long integer counts of seconds seen in the Question, extract an `Instant` from each of our `ZonedDateTime` objects, and ask for the seconds-since-epoch. Note that you might be losing data as the `ZonedDateTime`/`Instant` objects can store values with a resolution up to nanoseconds. The call asking for whole seconds from epoch means any fraction of a second is truncated.

```
long seconds1 = zdt.toInstant().getEpochSecond();
long seconds2 = zdtStartOfDay.toInstant().getEpochSecond();
```

Comment: Thank you for the fair play. +1.