# How to change miillisecond to Date Object in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format

Tags: java, datetime-format, epoch, milliseconds

How to change milliseconds to Date object in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format like 2017-04-12 23:14:52?

Comment: please provide the input milliseconds?

Comment: Do you understand that a `Date` object doesn't have a format? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: I hope this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format

Comment: What have you tried? Did you search before asking? *Very* funny if nothing useful and helpful turned up. It’s certainly already out there, and you can find it faster than anyone can type it once again here.

Comment: @Tim, the question you are linking to is only asking about (and getting) formatting into hours, minutes, seconds and millis, not year, month and day as is being asked for here. I agree with you that this question must have been asked and answered not only once before, but many times.

Comment: I also agree with you, @Tim, that there seems to be two questions in this one: (1) how to convert millis since the epoch to a date (or date-time) object (2) how to format said object. *Both* have been asked and answered many times before.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. For a couple of reasons.

**TL;DR**: Don’t use `Date`, use `Instant`. Neither of these can have a format in them. Formatting into a string is dependent on time zone, so you need to choose a time zone.

First, I understand from the discussion that you are asking for a `java.util.Date` object having the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. A `Date` object does not have and cannot have a format in it. The thing you should try to understand here is the difference between data itself and presentation of data to a user. An `int` may hold the value 25389, but it doesn’t hold it in the format 25389 (in fact the internal representation is quite different from 25389). The same `int` may be presented to a user as 25389, 000025389, 25,389 or +25389, just to mention a few out of many possibilities. The formatting happens outside the `int` while the `int` stays just the same.

Similarly, a `Date` object holds a point in time. The same date may be formatted into for example 2017-04-12 23:14:52 or April 12, 2017 11:14:52 PM. It may even be formatted for different time zones, which would be a good idea if the system has users in different time zones. Alternatively we may show the user a calendar leaf and/or a clock showing the time. Again, formatting happens outside of the `Date` while the `Date` stays just the same.

Elaborating on the time zone issue, the same point in time represented by the same millisecond value could be formatted to 2017-04-12 17:44:52 in UTC, 2017-04-12 19:44:52 in my time zone, 2017-04-12 23:14:52 in Asia/Kolkata time zone or even 2017-04-13 05:44:52 in Pacific/Auckland time zone. Note that in the last case not even the date is the same. So there is not just one way to change your milliseconds into the format you asked for. We need to know which time zone you want it for before we can help you.

So what I believe you need is not one thing, but two

1. A way to store your point in time in your program.
2. A way to format your point in time into a string in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format for a user in some time zone.

For storing your point in time, use either of

- A `long` for the milliseconds value you already have
- A `java.time.Instant` object.

Why didn’t I mention `java.util.Date`? Because this class is long outdated. Its design turned out to be troublesome very quickly. They tried to repair it by deprecating most of the methods and introducing `java.util.Calendar`, but that didn’t work very well either. Finally, drawing on the experiences from a library known as Joda-Time they introduced the `java.time` classes in Java 8 in 2014. That’s three years ago as of writing, and counting. So IMHO we should by now have thrown `Date` and friends overboard and started using the newer classes. So prefer `Instant` over `Date`.

Changing your milliseconds to an `Instant` is straightforward:

```
    long milliseconds = 1492019092000L;
    Instant pointInTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds);
```

For formatting your instant into a string for the user, as I said, we require a time zone. Then do

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDateTimeString = pointInTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
            .format(formatter);
```

So you need to fill in the desired time zone where I put `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")`. If you want to use the JVM’s current time zone setting, just fill in `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. Beware, though, that the time zone setting may be changed, even by an unrelated program running in the same JVM, so relying on this may be fragile.

The result of the above code snippet is a string like

```
2017-04-12 23:14:52
```

PS If after reading the above you really insist, here’s how to get a `java.util.Date` from the above:

```
    Date myOutdatedDateInstance = Date.from(pointInTime);
```

(and excuse me for repeating, it still doesn’t have the desired format, that is not possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sample code.

```
public class MillDateConverter {

    public static String dFormat = "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    private static SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dFormat);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long milliSec=Long.parseLong("1086073200000");
        System.out.println(milliSec);
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSec);
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

    }

}
```

Comment: By doing this i will get String simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()) returns String but i want java.utill.Date Object. I tried doing simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())) after getting the String but then i am getting Tue Apr 25 23:52:17 IST 2017 format which i don't want

Comment: You are asking the impossible, or maybe rather, the self-contradictory, @NilenduKumar. A `java.util.Date` object hasn’t got and cannot have a format in it. It’s a point in time, nothing more.