# Java GET returning date as a 13 digit number

Tags: java, json, spring, date

My web application returns a date as a 13 digit number, such as `1475166540000`.

How to format it into a proper date to be returned in the JSON response. In my function it just returns the whole DTO.

Comment: Looks like epoch time, why you get that depends on how you generate the JSON which you have not shared.

Comment: to answer your question we need to know how are you querying DB, your DTO and how you are creating JSON. Because there are a lot of ways to implement it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java convert milliseconds to time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_475_166_540_000L )
       .toString()
```

Or…

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( Long.parseLong( "1475166540000" ) )
       .toString()
```

## Details

An `Instant` represents a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

That class can parse a count of milliseconds from the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_475_166_540_000L ) ;
```

Ditto for count of whole seconds, by the way, `Instant.ofEpochSecond( mySeconds )`.

If the input is a `String`, parse into a `long`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( Long.parseLong( "1475166540000" ) ) ;
```

To generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2016-09-29T16:29:00Z

The `Z` on the end is short for “Zulu” and means UTC.

> How to format it into a proper date

No such thing as a “proper date”. Every culture has their own way of textually displaying date-time values.

For localized display to users, use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and its `ofLocalized…` methods.

```
String output = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime​( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.JAPAN ) ) ;  // Use Japanese formatting to display a moment in Tunisia wall-clock time.
```

> 2016年9月29日木曜日 17時29分00秒 中央ヨーロッパ標準時

For exchanging data between systems such as JSON, **use only the standard ISO 8601 formats**. They are practical, designed to be unambiguous and easy to parse by machine as well as easy to read by humans across cultures. The *java.time* class built into Java use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2016-09-29T16:29:00Z

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-09-29T16:29:00Z" ) ;
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

> 1475166540000

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use the troublesome  `Date`/`Calendar` classes seen in your example code. They are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the *java.time* classes.

To inter-operate with old code not yet updated to java.time, you can convert back and forth. Call on New conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Date d = Date.from( instant ) ;  // Don’t do this unless forced to inter-operate with old code not yet updated to java.time classes.
```

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 you can use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library :

```
String date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
        Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.valueOf("1475166540000")), ZoneId.systemDefault()
).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

System.out.println(date);// 2016-09-29 17:29:00
```

Comment: The `LocalDateTime` class is misleading here, as it purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Answer (score 1):

That 13-digit number is a Unix timestamp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time
It's the number of milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970, at midnight, in UTC.

To convert it to a `Date`, just do:

```
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong("1475166540000"));
```

If you use Java 8 or higher, refer to the other answers