# Java File last modified in default timezone?

Tags: java, file, date

I'd like to get the last modified date in my computers timezone (same that I see in the windows file explorer)

```
System.out.println(myFile.lastModified()); // I get UTC
```

Comment: `"same that I see "`.. how do we can know what do you see? Why don't give us the example and let us determine by ourselves? Please, include this information to your question. :))

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java convert milliseconds to time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format). There are many other similar questions and answers, please use your search engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From documentation [`myFile.lastModified()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified--)

> **Returns:** A long value representing the time the file was last modified, measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT,
>   January 1, 1970), or 0L if the file does not exist or if an I/O error
>   occurs

So you need to convert it to a date, if you are using Java 8+, you can use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API like so :

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
        Instant.ofEpochMilli(myFile.lastModified()), ZoneId.systemDefault()
);

System.out.println(date);//example result : 2018-06-06T15:05:19.113
```

---

If you want more precision you can use :

```
File myFile = new File("pathname");
Long timeMs = myFile.lastModified();
if (timeMs != 0) {
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
            Instant.ofEpochMilli(myFile.lastModified()), ZoneId.systemDefault()
    );
    System.out.println(date);
}else{
    System.out.println("File not exist!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `ZonedDateTime` object and apply the system's default time offset to it.

```
ZonedDateTime zt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(myFile.lastModified()), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

You can then simply print out this object or work further with it.